# Angularjs : Texbox value not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-module

In agularjs controller I am creating variable

```
var search = [];
search.area = 'xyz';
$scope.search = search;
```

And in html page

```
 <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control" data-ng-model="search.area" placeholder="Area">
```

So, after loading the page default value doesn't being display as 'xyz' in textbox.

Please guide !!

Comment: this should work. please put some more codes.

Comment: If possible can you paste your complete code.

Answer (score 2):

There is some problem with your controller:-)
Your code is working fine

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl"><input type="text" name="area" class="form-control" data-ng-model="search.area" placeholder="Area"/>

    </div>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var search = [];
    search.area = 'xyz';
    $scope.search = search;
    }
</script>
```

Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/4rwnefnL/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing angular library Or controller is different in which you are declaring search variable.

Or Might be `ng-app="myApp"` (tell angular to initialize on page) is missing from your HTML.

Always do follow modular approach in angular by creating module.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  // controller code here
})
.directive('myDir', function(){
  return {
    //directive code here
  }
})
.filter('customfilter', function(){
  return function(val){
    //filter code here
  }
})
.factory('customFactory', function(){
  return function(val){
    //filter code here
  }
})
```

Follow above code to design angular app.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/195/)

Comment: @Arvind Kushwaha you have too many options to accept answer..why you don't do it.?